# Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'

Tags: flutter, build, app-bundle

Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.AppPlugin$ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtensionImplCompat.

> Could not generate a decorated class for type AppPlugin.ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtensionImplCompat.
> Cannot have abstract method AndroidComponentsExtension.registerSourceType().

Tried to build appbundle in flutter to get a release aab file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.